# DateTime Conversion issue

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a string value in the following format.  23-SEP-10 10.48.53.0000 AM

When I try a DateTime.Parse() or a Convert.ToDateTime() on this string I get the following error.

```
"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
```

What do I need to do in order to get this to work?  Thanks

Comment: What language/platform are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming .NET, you should be using a [custom DateTime format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), in conjunction with `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact`.

Example in C#:

```
var parsedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("23-SEP-10 10.48.53.0000 AM", 
                                         "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.FFFF tt", 
                                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the format you want to convert to then you should use DateTime.ParseExact. otherwise DateTime.Parse compares the date with millions of formats which you don't want.